# Re-mapping Swedish letters

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

On a Swedish keyboard to the right of the keyboard one has:
`O`, `P`, `Å`
`L`, `Ö`, `Ä`

`[` and `]` are extensively used by Vim, and hard to reach on my keyboard, so therefore I've mapped these to `Ö` and `Ä` in my `.vimrc` file.

```
map ö [
map ä ]
```

I'd like `<leader>[`, or in reality `<leader>ö` to move a line up. So I've tried:

```
" Does not work
nmap <leader>[ :m .+1<CR>==
" Works
nmap <leader>ö :m .+1<CR>==
```

Note that I don't want to have special characters `Ö` and `Ä` in my vimrc file, in order to keep it universal. I've tried different combinations of map, nmap, and nnoremap, without success. 
Note that I always want `Ö` and `Ä` to be remapped, except for when writing in insert mode. Now I can use them normally in insert mode, which is unexpected.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Are you looking for [`:h 'langmap'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27langmap%27)? Something like `set langmap=ö[` to make `ö` behave like `[` in normal mode and then your mapping should work. (Also unless you know what you are doing, you should use the non recursive version of the mapping commands `nnoremap`)

Comment: I tested `set langmap=ö[ä]` but didn't work still. Still, this mapping works
`nnoremap <leader>ö :m .+1<CR>==`, this doesn't `nnoremap <leader>[ :m .+1<CR>==`.

Comment: A thought, could it be that using the normal `[]` keys requires me to use `ALT-GR`, and they don't work with the leader key. This seems to be related to `meta` keys sending some key combination that includes an `ESC`, [or something similar](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Get_Alt_key_to_work_in_terminal). Maybe the mappings work, but it's the map to the bracket that messes it up.

Comment: I just tried this one and couldn't make `'langmap'` work either... In theory it should work, so I don't know why it doesn't... Is it completely broken? Not very sure how to troubleshoot it either since the translation happens at a fairly low level... Maybe need to increase verbosity to understand what's going on there?

Comment: Hi, can I assist you with here? Good that the bug is reproducible.